# send and convert multiple arrays from android to php server

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

I am very new in android.
I am very confused how to convert this array into a JSON array sends it to the server php :

```
{"menu":[{"id":"2","number":"3"},
{"id":"6","number":"4"},
{"id":"5","number":"6"}],
"user":[{"uid": "12345","number":"imam@imam.com"}],
"table":[{"number":"7"}]}
```

Comment: Please add some of your code and specify where you are *very confused* - this question is far too broad. Be more specific. Show us some code you've already written (if at all), or start -goo...- using a search engine.

Comment: You don't have to convert that json text. Just send it as is.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$myArr = json_decode($json); //array('menu' => ..., 'user' => ..., 'table' => ...)
```